# ssh tunneling command from ssh/config file is not working on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ssh, portforwarding, ubuntu-20.04, ssh-tunnel

I have following configuration in my ~/.ssh/config file:

```
Host github.myteam.tun
 User johndoe
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/johndoe
ProxyCommand ssh -L 2443:github.myteam.dev:443 -f -v -N -o ControlMaster=no -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=3 -o TCPKeepAlive=no -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o ServerAliveCountMax=1 cs.gate
```

When I type command:

```
ssh github.myteam.tun
```

it gives such error:

> kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

However if I paste command:

```
ssh -L 2443:github.myteam.dev:443 -f -v -N -o ControlMaster=no -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o NumberOfPasswordPrompts=3 -o TCPKeepAlive=no -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o ServerAliveCountMax=1 cs.gate
```

It works fine.

It seems this is because of ubuntu version 20.04. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [`ProxyCommand`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ProxyCommand) is used if you want to tunnel the ssh connection itself through another command - which is not what you are trying to do here!

Instead try the following configuration

```
Host github.myteam.tun
    User johndoe
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/johndoe
    Hostname cs.gate
    LocalForward 2443 github.myteam.dev:443 # ssh -L
    ForkAfterAuthentication yes # ssh -f
    SessionType none # ssh -N
    LogLevel VERBOSE # ssh -v
    ControlMaster no
    ExitOnForwardFailure yes
    ConnectTimeout 10
    NumberOfPasswordPrompts 3
    TCPKeepAlive no
    ServerAliveInterval 60
    ServerAliveCountMax 1
```